# APEX Get variables in the string

Tags: apex

This is my sample code

I expect the result
**texts = (A, B, C, D).**

```
String text = 'Hi {!A} , welcome to {!B},If you are traveling and have any questions,pls contact {!C}' + 
'best wishes {!D}';
List<String> texts = new List<String>();
Integer textNumber = text.countMatches('{!');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'textNumber = ' + textNumber);

for (Integer i = 0 ; i < textNumber ; i++ ) {
    if (i == 0) {
        texts.add(text.substringBetween('{!', '}'));
        text = text.removeStart('{!');
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'text = ' + text);
    } else {
        String removeString = text;
        texts.add(removeString.substringBetween('{!', '}'));
    }
}
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'texts = ' + texts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `removeStart` it just tries to find if the first element in my String is `{!` , only then it removes that.

From Doc :

> Removes the specified substring only if it occurs at the beginning of the String.

You can use a split by `{!`

and then capture the String inbetween your eachString.

for eg:

```
String text = 'Hi {!A} , welcome to {!B},If you are traveling and have any questions,pls contact {!C}' +
        'best wishes {!D}';
List<String> texts = new List<String>();
Integer textNumber = text.countMatches('{!');

List<String> strings = text.split('\\{!');
Set<String> uniqueStrings = new Set<String>();
for(String eachString : strings){
    uniqueStrings.add(eachString.substringBetween('', '}'));
}
uniqueStrings.remove(null);


System.debug(uniqueStrings);
```

`08:33:38.8 (9933621)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|{A, B, C, D}`